# Python - Multiplying an element from a dictionary nested in a list by another element from the same dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a challenge that I need to complete for Codio, but I'm stuck. The challenge is to create a list of dictionaries that are grocery items (you'll see what I mean in the 'while' statement). Then find the cost of each item by multiplying the price by the number of that item, then adding them all up and displaying it. I keep receiving the error:

> "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

when I attempt to multiply value*value2. I have specified which dictionary within the list to pull key/values from (by setting x equal to the number of elements in the list) and which key/value to pull a number from, so I don't know what's going on exactly. How would I multiply the value of 'number' by the value of 'price'? The code below is just one of many methods I have tried.
Thanks!

```
grocery_item = {}
grocery_history = []
stop = 'go'

while stop!='q':
    item_name=input("Item name:\n")
    quantity=int(input("Quantity purchased:\n"))
    cost=float(input("Price per item:\n"))
    grocery_item={'name':item_name, 'number':int(quantity), 'price':float(cost)}
    grocery_history.append(grocery_item)

    stop=input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit")

grand_total=0

#Define a 'for' loop.  

for x in range(0, len(grocery_history)):
    value=float(grocery_history[x]['number'])
    value2=float(grocery_history[x]['price'])
  #Calculate the total cost for the grocery_item.
    item_total="%.2f" % value*value2
  #Add the item_total to the grand_total
    grand_total="%.2f" % float(grand_total+item_total)
  #Output the information for the grocery item to match this example:
  #2 apple @ $1.49 ea $2.98
    print (grocery_history[x]['number']+"  "+grocery_history[x]['name']+" @ "+grocery_history[x]['price']+" ea  $"+grand_total)

    item_total=0

print (grand_total)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.
You've given us about 20 lines of code for a one-line problem.  Get rid of the overhead: replace `value` and `value2` with constants (such as 5 and 1.49), and give us the single-line version.  The dictionaries and osummation are insignificant to your error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting caught by operator precedence.  Use parentheses, or simply move your formatting to the `print` statement.

```
item_total = value*value2   # format later
```

or

```
item_total="%.2f" % (value*value2)
```

Comment: Awesome, right on! Thanks so much! There were some other errors I encountered, but I was able to fix them.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.